# Clarification on definition of structure and theory of a structure in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

In the context of first order logic, if I read the sentence:

Let's $\mathcal{M}$ be a structure, and let's $T$ be its theory, what it is $T$ precisely?

I hope the question is clear.
Let me try to respond myself, and see if I misunderstood something.

The definition of theory I have in mind is the one that given a set $\Sigma$ of "initial" sentences (written using an specific formal language from a concrete first order logic),  is another set of sentences $\Sigma_1$ that contains all the sentences (written in the very same specific formal language) such as the concrete first order logic (the fixed set of logical and equality axioms written in the specific formal language) is able to provide a proof. In short $\Sigma_1$ = { $\varphi : \Sigma \vdash \varphi $  }

"Let's $\mathcal{M}$ be a structure", implicitly says that there is a concrete first order logic, with a concrete formal language (a fix set of logical and non-logical symbols), with a concrete axioms of logic and equality, a concrete set of non-logical axioms and a fixed interpretation that maps the non-logical symbols into the structure, making the non-logical axioms true?

Theory of $\mathcal{M}$ is by definition the theory of the non-logical axioms that implictly exists from the previous paragraph?

On the other side if I look at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic) it says:

> Theories associated with a structure

> Each structure has several
> associated theories. The complete theory of a structure A is the set
> of all first-order sentences over the signature of A which are
> satisfied by A.

When it says each structure has **several** associated theories. It is counting as a diferent theory any theory built from any set of non-logical axioms (written in the fixed language and logical axioms...) that **becomes true under the fixed interpretation**?

As a side question the previous set is the same set if I define it as **sentences being provable** in the syntactic side of fixed first order logic? The last question, it is "true" by the first order completeness theorem?

EDIT:
Probably I would delete the question. I think now I have a clearer picture of what is the expected way of thinking on a FOL setup.
It is a three side game.

FIRST PLAYER: the language.

Because it is a "first order" language, it is already equipped with some fix logical predicate symbols (depending on the logical axioms  and rules of inferences used by deduction aparatus).

Additionally there are enough variable symbols (to be able to point into as many specified individuals to the future domain as we wish).

At the same time like a placeholder ready to be filled, the language is ready to accept as many constant symbols as we wish (to be able to refer to as many specific individuals of our future domain), and ready to accept as many function symbols and non logical predicate symbols as we wish of any arity.

The set of non logical symbols (constant, function, predicate) we are willing to accept is called the signature of the first order language.

The language has already defined (builtin) the way the symbols can be combined to create terms, formulas and sentences.

So at this point the language (as long as you provide a signature) is ready to produce as many sentences as you wish.

Summarizing, if you give me a signature I would give you back a factory of sentence.

SECOND PLAYER: the logic

The deductive aparatus. The syntactic side.

Here we have a built-in fixed set of logical and equality axioms schemas ready to be automatically filled (as soon as the non logical symbols are set).
It contains some fixed rules of inferences too.

The only thing he needs to start is a set of non-logical axioms $\Sigma$ (sentences written using the first player).

After getting axioms the logical aparatus is ready to run and is able to produce theorems $\phi$ (provable sentences)

In formal terms: $\Sigma\vdash\phi$

THIRD PLAYER: The semantic side.

It expects a structure. A structure is a matematical construction that has two things: a domain and a "signature".

The domain, is the set where individuals belong.

The "signature" is the semantic counterpart of the non-logical symbols (the signature). In the syntactic side we have constant symbols, function symbols and predicate symbols, and in the semantic side just constants, functions and predicates.

The semantic side has a built-in procedure to translate sentences written by the language. It follows Tarsky rules of truth.

At the semantic side the translated sentences are true or false by definition. It is another fixed setting of First Order Logic.

The semantic side can be used in two diferent ways.

Playing with the second player, the axioms of the second player must be true. Then if a given sentence $\phi$ is true under this interpretation, formally we say: $\Sigma\vDash\phi$

But there is another way playing, the part I missed completely. The first player can write sentences and pass them to the third player without the second player knowing.

And we can think if that set of sentences $\Sigma$ are true or false in the semantic side.

Hopefully what I write make more sense now...

Comment: See [Theories associated with a structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic)#Theories_associated_with_a_structure).

Comment: More specifically, for a structure $\mathcal M$, its *theory* is the set of all first-order sentences that are satisfied by $\mathcal M$.

Comment: Not very clear what $\Sigma$ mean: the axioms of the theory? If so, we may imagine that it is the set of FO Peano's axioms. Thus $\Sigma \vdash \phi$ means that $\phi$ is a theorem of arithmetic (example: $1 < 2$).

Comment: The Completeness Th for FOL says: $\Sigma \vDash \phi \text { iff } \Sigma \vdash \phi$.

Comment: The first order sentences I write I am inclined to think that belongs to the sintantic side. A think that I put as axioms in my deductive systems and see what happens, or a sentence from which I try to figure out a proof, a syntactic proof (a set of sentences finishing with the one I have). I never thought about writing a sentence and looking directly at them via the semantic side.  When I say $\Sigma$ here I was refering to any undefined set of sentences I could write with the language and see what happens when I consider them as axioms, without thinking before if they were true at all...

Comment: Just to reiterate in a "funny way" for me the completness Th for FOL says:  $\Sigma \vdash \phi \text { iff } \Sigma \vDash \phi$

Comment: And $\Sigma \vDash \phi$ means $\phi$ is true in all interpretations that make $\Sigma$ true. That's the whole point, if there is an interpretation in which $\phi$ is true and another one in which $\phi$ is false then you know $\phi$ is undecidable in the syntantic theorem factory built from $\Sigma$. I know you know. I am just writing this to make sure they are rigth. I will interpret no response as a yes :)